# Как передать пиксель з приленда на ленд Php?

Tags: php, fb2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="theme_dark">
   <head>
      
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Telegram: Max Cox ⚪️</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://telegram.org/favicon.ico?3" type="image/x-icon">
      <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/telegram.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
      <script>
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
        {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
        if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
        n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
        'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq('init', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['pixel_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>');
        fbq('track', 'PageView');
      </script>
      <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['pixel_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
   </head>
   <body class>
      <div class="tgme_background_wrap">
         <canvas id="tgme_background" class="tgme_background default" data-colors="4e00b3,090979,00d4ff" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
         <div class="tgme_background_pattern default"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tgme_page_wrap">
         <div class="tgme_head_wrap">
            <div class="tgme_head">
               <a  href="https://telegram.org/" class="tgme_head_brand">
               <img src="images/Telegram-App-Logo-PNG-1024x848.png" alt="Telegram" height="40px">
               </a>
               <a  class="tgme_head_right_btn" href="https://telegram.org/dl">
               Download
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tgme_body_wrap">
            <div class="tgme_page">
               <div class="tgme_page_photo">
                  <a  onclick="fbq('track', 'Lead');" href="tg://resolve?domain=cox_in_crypto"><img class="tgme_page_photo_image" src="images/logovip.jpg"></a>
               </div>
               <div class="tgme_page_title"><span dir="auto">Max Cox ⚪️</span></div>
               <div class="tgme_page_extra">
                  9 009 subscribers
               </div>
               <div class="tgme_page_description ">Making your portfolio BIGGER! <br>
I give FREE signals EVERY DAY! <br>
Join my TELEGRAM 
               </div>
               <div class="tgme_page_action">
                  <a  onclick="fbq('track', 'Lead');" class="tgme_action_button_new shine" href="tg://resolve?domain=cox_in_crypto">Write me</a>
               </div>
               <!-- WEBOGRAM_BTN -->
               <!-- PRIVACY_BTN -->
               
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="js/tgwallpaper.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // function pixelfb(e) {
        //    let t = document.createElement("img");
        //    t.height = "1", t.width = "1", t.style = "display:none", t.src = "https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=" + e + "&ev=lead&noscript=1"
        // }
        // var params = window.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&").reduce(function (e, t) {
        //       var o = t.split("=");
        //       return e[decodeURIComponent(o[0])] = decodeURIComponent(o[1]), e
        //    }, {}),
        //    par = params.pixel_id;
         
         var url = "tg://resolve?domain=cox_in_crypto";
         setTimeout(function() {
            // pixelfb(par); 
            window.location = url;     
         }, 2000);
        
      </script>
      <style>
         .tgme_page {
         padding: 10px;
         }    
         @media (min-width: 1024px) {
         .tgme_body_wrap {
         padding: 100px;
         }
         }
         a.tgme_action_button_new, a.tgme_head_right_btn {
         background-color: #26a3dd;
         color: #fff;
         }
      </style>
   </body>
</html>
```